# Codeigniter Command line error - PHP Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line

After following the user guide instructions found here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html I'm unable to run the test script via command line.

My controller located at /var/www/mysite/application/controllers/

```
    class Tools extends CI_Controller {

    public function message($to = 'World')
    {
        echo "Hello {$to}!".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

In my browser I can access

```
http://mysite/tools/message/ben
```

And the function correctly outputs "Hello ben"

From terminal I should be able to run:

> $ php index.php tools message "Ben"

My terminal should print: "Hello Ben"

However I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CI_Controller' not found in /var/www/mysite/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 233

My server is pretty standard; ubuntu LAMP. Codeigniter is pretty standard too and I have no problem running non CI scripts via command line

My PHP binary is only located in /usr/bin/php <-- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322587/codeigniter-command-line-cron-cpanel/11156257#11156257) suggests an issue running CI directly from usr/bin/php, however I'm not operating a shared PHP service, and I don't see why this would make a difference to how PHP executes a CI script.

Any help or just an indication on how to debug this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I take it you are running the script from /var/www/mysite/ ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I would immediately get a "Could not open input file" error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved! (partly) the issue was CodeIgniters error logging.

In application/config/config.php, I modified the following config property:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
```

This disables logging, and allows `$ php index.php` to execute.

If anyone can explain why CI only shows this error on CLI PHP - might help anyone else who has this issue and needs it resolved with error logging on.

Answer (score 10):

This error is often due to not being able to connect to the database.  Yes, indeed, judging by the error message, they have nothing to do with each other.  Nevertheless, this seems to be first visible error that comes up, when the framework is unable to connect to the database.

So, to solve the error "**Class 'CI_Controller' not found**", as a starting point, review your database settings (Application -> Config -> database.php), such as  `*hostname*, *username*, *password* and *database*` and see if they are correct and if you can connect manually.

Comment: I understand, that you haven't had enough reputation to post comments yet, but this answer really looks like one. Try adding more details into it.

Comment: @sanjeev goel You are pointing us at right direction, but it takes me one hour to understand and figure out that whole thing. In my case problem is due to db driver of CI, since DB on local server was deleted by team developer so CI is giving this error. But obviously error from CI is not understandable.

Comment: right.. see you configuration database. database name, username and password must match.

Comment: Hi, this is true, please check you have the right  database, the right username and password and if all this is correct then you can try to export your database, drop the existing one and create another one then import your db back, remember to change the name in database.php if you changed it in database

Answer (score 2):

To Mijahn:

I had this same problem, and after about two hours of tracing through code to figure out the problem, it seems that there is some sort of conflict with loading the CI_Controller when utilizing the native PHP load_class function.

I worked around this issue by making the following changes to the Common.php file (hack, I know).

```
//$_log =& load_class('Log');
require_once('system/libraries/Log.php');
$_log = new CI_Log();
```

My logs then where created exactly like I wanted. Hope this hack helps.

Comment: For me it wasn't the Log class myking problems but the exception handler in Common.php
So I had to change the loading of the Exceptions class accordingly:

    `// $_error =& load_class('Exceptions', 'core');
    require_once('system/core/Exceptions.php');
    $_error = new CI_Exceptions('core');`

Answer (score 0):

This [site](http://larrykagan.com/blog/view/CodeIgniter-from-the-Command-Line) says to run codeigniter from the command line, one must set the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] variable.

> $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is usually supplied by php when a web request is made. However, since we are calling this script from the command line, we need to emulate this small part of the environment as a web request.

Comment: Thanks, in the link its using a PHP doc outside the CI application folder, and loads CI by including index.php. I need to run commands on a CI controller within my application. I did change my $config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO", but still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932372/codeigniter-fatal-error-class-ci-controller-not-found-after-upgrade-php-and) worked for me.

Within `system/core/CodeIgniter.php`, on around line 75, change:

`set_error_handler('_exception_handler');`

to...

`set_exception_handler('_exception_handler');`

Other users have reported that this gave them a better backtrace with which to debug the underlying issue, but for me, this actually removed the problem altogether.