# How to use `Composer` to add Codeigniter helper in a project?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, composer-php, codeigniter-form-helper

In order to learn how composer works

I created `composer.json` to download codeigniter with all dependencies

```
{
    "require": {
        "rogeriopradoj/codeigniter": "2.1.4"
    }
}
```

then created `vendor` directory using `composer`

After loading all these I want to just use form helpers that comes with codeigniter and I want to all this using composer(to know how composer works).

I created index.php having the following code and also have included `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

```
<?php
// file name : index.php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


class A extends CI_Controller
{   
    public function home()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        echo form_open('email/send');

        $data = array(
                      'name'        => 'username',
                      'id'          => 'username',
                      'value'       => 'johndoe',
                      'maxlength'   => '100',
                      'size'        => '50',
                      'style'       => 'width:50%',
                    );

        echo form_input($data);
        echo form_close("</div>");      
    }

}

$a = new A;
$a->home();

?>
```

When I visit `127.0.0.1/index.php` I get the following error

`Notice: Undefined property: A::$load in C:\xampp\htdocs\M\index.php on line 14`

`Fatal error: Call to a member function helper() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\M\index.php on line 14`

So its not working the way I wanted,anyone please explain what's wrong?

## Update

After including form helpers but still getting this error,I have included `vendor/autoload.php`

`Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\M\index.php on line 7`

Answer (score 1):

You've not set `$load`. It's like your doing something like `null -> helper ();` which explains the "call on a non object" error.

**Edit** : For your Class not found error, you could give a look at this :

[Codeigniter Command line error - PHP Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207937/codeigniter-command-line-error-php-fatal-error-class-ci-controller-not-foun)

Comment: Now I added $this->load->helper(); but still it does not work, "CI_Controller not found"

Comment: Did you include the file containing the CI_Controller class ? Maybe it is in the `vendor/autoload.php` file ? Add the new error to your main post as an edit please.

Comment: I have added vendor/autoload.php, considering that it would take care of CI_Controller class

Comment: Edited my answer to add a link to a similar question on SO. Check it out, there are chances that you've the same problem.