# codeigniter - fatal error class 'CI_Controller' not found after upgrade php and apache

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, upgrade

i am upgrade
     apache From 2.2.19.0 To 2.4.16.0
And
     php From 5.3.7.0 To 5.6.12.0
now i get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 234

CodeIgniter.php line 221-235

```
// Load the base controller class
require BASEPATH.'core/Controller.php';

/**
 * Reference to the CI_Controller method.
 *
 * Returns current CI instance object
 *
 * @return object
 */

function &get_instance()
{
    return CI_Controller::get_instance();
}
```

Full CodeIgniter.php

```
<?php
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.2.4 or newer
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * Licensed under the Open Software License version 3.0
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0) that is
 * bundled with this package in the files license.txt / license.rst.  It is
 * also available through the world wide web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/OSL-3.0
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to obtain it
 * through the world wide web, please send an email to
 * licensing@ellislab.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      EllisLab Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2013, EllisLab, Inc. (http://ellislab.com/)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/OSL-3.0 Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * System Initialization File
 *
 * Loads the base classes and executes the request.
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  CodeIgniter
 * @category    Front-controller
 * @author      EllisLab Dev Team
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/
 */

/**
 * CodeIgniter Version
 *
 * @var string
 *
 */
    define('CI_VERSION', '3.0-dev');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Load the global functions
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    require_once(BASEPATH.'core/Common.php');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Load the framework constants
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    if (file_exists(APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/constants.php'))
    {
        require(APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/constants.php');
    }
    else
    {
        require(APPPATH.'config/constants.php');
    }

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Define a custom error handler so we can log PHP errors
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    set_error_handler('_exception_handler');

    if ( ! is_php('5.4'))
    {
        @ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0); // Kill magic quotes
    }

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Set the subclass_prefix
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Normally the "subclass_prefix" is set in the config file.
 * The subclass prefix allows CI to know if a core class is
 * being extended via a library in the local application
 * "libraries" folder. Since CI allows config items to be
 * overriden via data set in the main index. php file,
 * before proceeding we need to know if a subclass_prefix
 * override exists. If so, we will set this value now,
 * before any classes are loaded
 * Note: Since the config file data is cached it doesn't
 * hurt to load it here.
 */
    if ( ! empty($assign_to_config['subclass_prefix']))
    {
        get_config(array('subclass_prefix' => $assign_to_config['subclass_prefix']));
    }

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Start the timer... tick tock tick tock...
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $BM =& load_class('Benchmark', 'core');
    $BM->mark('total_execution_time_start');
    $BM->mark('loading_time:_base_classes_start');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Instantiate the hooks class
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $EXT =& load_class('Hooks', 'core');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Is there a "pre_system" hook?
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $EXT->_call_hook('pre_system');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Instantiate the config class
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $CFG =& load_class('Config', 'core');

    // Do we have any manually set config items in the index.php file?
    if (isset($assign_to_config) && is_array($assign_to_config))
    {
        foreach ($assign_to_config as $key => $value)
        {
            $CFG->set_item($key, $value);
        }
    }

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Instantiate the UTF-8 class
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Note: Order here is rather important as the UTF-8
 * class needs to be used very early on, but it cannot
 * properly determine if UTF-8 can be supported until
 * after the Config class is instantiated.
 *
 */
    $UNI =& load_class('Utf8', 'core');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Instantiate the URI class
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $URI =& load_class('URI', 'core');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Instantiate the routing class and set the routing
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $RTR =& load_class('Router', 'core');
    $RTR->_set_routing();

    // Set any routing overrides that may exist in the main index file
    if (isset($routing))
    {
        $RTR->_set_overrides($routing);
    }

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Instantiate the output class
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $OUT =& load_class('Output', 'core');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Is there a valid cache file? If so, we're done...
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    if ($EXT->_call_hook('cache_override') === FALSE
        && $OUT->_display_cache($CFG, $URI) === TRUE)
    {
        exit;
    }

/*
 * -----------------------------------------------------
 * Load the security class for xss and csrf support
 * -----------------------------------------------------
 */
    $SEC =& load_class('Security', 'core');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Load the Input class and sanitize globals
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $IN =& load_class('Input', 'core');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Load the Language class
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $LANG =& load_class('Lang', 'core');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Load the app controller and local controller
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *
 */
    // Load the base controller class
    require BASEPATH.'core/Controller.php';

    /**
     * Reference to the CI_Controller method.
     *
     * Returns current CI instance object
     *
     * @return object
     */

    function &get_instance()
    {
        return CI_Controller::get_instance();
    }

    if (file_exists(APPPATH.'core/'.$CFG->config['subclass_prefix'].'Controller.php'))
    {
        require APPPATH.'core/'.$CFG->config['subclass_prefix'].'Controller.php';
    }

    // Load the local application controller
    // Note: The Router class automatically validates the controller path using the router->_validate_request().
    // If this include fails it means that the default controller in the Routes.php file is not resolving to something valid.
    if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$RTR->directory.$RTR->class.'.php'))
    {
        show_error('Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.');
    }

    include(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$RTR->directory.$RTR->class.'.php');

    // Set a mark point for benchmarking
    $BM->mark('loading_time:_base_classes_end');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Security check
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *  None of the methods in the app controller or the
 *  loader class can be called via the URI, nor can
 *  controller functions that begin with an underscore.
 */
    $class  = $RTR->class;
    $method = $RTR->method;

    if ( ! class_exists($class, FALSE) OR $method[0] === '_' OR method_exists('CI_Controller', $method))
    {
        if ( ! empty($RTR->routes['404_override']))
        {
            if (sscanf($RTR->routes['404_override'], '%[^/]/%s', $class, $method) !== 2)
            {
                $method = 'index';
            }

            if ( ! class_exists($class, FALSE))
            {
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class.'.php'))
                {
                    show_404($class.'/'.$method);
                }

                include_once(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class.'.php');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            show_404($class.'/'.$method);
        }
    }

    if (method_exists($class, '_remap'))
    {
        $params = array($method, array_slice($URI->rsegments, 2));
        $method = '_remap';
    }
    else
    {
        // WARNING: It appears that there are issues with is_callable() even in PHP 5.2!
        // Furthermore, there are bug reports and feature/change requests related to it
        // that make it unreliable to use in this context. Please, DO NOT change this
        // work-around until a better alternative is available.
        if ( ! in_array(strtolower($method), array_map('strtolower', get_class_methods($class)), TRUE))
        {
            if (empty($RTR->routes['404_override']))
            {
                show_404($class.'/'.$method);
            }
            elseif (sscanf($RTR->routes['404_override'], '%[^/]/%s', $class, $method) !== 2)
            {
                $method = 'index';
            }

            if ( ! class_exists($class, FALSE))
            {
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class.'.php'))
                {
                    show_404($class.'/'.$method);
                }

                include_once(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class.'.php');
            }
        }

        $params = array_slice($URI->rsegments, 2);
    }

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Is there a "pre_controller" hook?
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $EXT->_call_hook('pre_controller');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Instantiate the requested controller
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    // Mark a start point so we can benchmark the controller
    $BM->mark('controller_execution_time_( '.$class.' / '.$method.' )_start');

    $CI = new $class();

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Is there a "post_controller_constructor" hook?
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $EXT->_call_hook('post_controller_constructor');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Call the requested method
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    call_user_func_array(array(&$CI, $method), $params);

    // Mark a benchmark end point
    $BM->mark('controller_execution_time_( '.$class.' / '.$method.' )_end');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Is there a "post_controller" hook?
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $EXT->_call_hook('post_controller');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Send the final rendered output to the browser
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    if ($EXT->_call_hook('display_override') === FALSE)
    {
        $OUT->_display();
    }

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Is there a "post_system" hook?
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $EXT->_call_hook('post_system');

/* End of file CodeIgniter.php */
/* Location: ./system/core/CodeIgniter.php */
```

Full Controller.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2011, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @license     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * CodeIgniter Application Controller Class
 *
 * This class object is the super class that every library in
 * CodeIgniter will be assigned to.
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Libraries
 * @category    Libraries
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html
 */
class CI_Controller {

    private static $instance;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$instance =& $this;

        // Assign all the class objects that were instantiated by the
        // bootstrap file (CodeIgniter.php) to local class variables
        // so that CI can run as one big super object.
        foreach (is_loaded() as $var => $class)
        {
            $this->$var =& load_class($class);
        }

        $this->load =& load_class('Loader', 'core');

        $this->load->initialize();

        log_message('debug', "Controller Class Initialized");
    }

    public static function &get_instance()
    {
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
// END Controller class

/* End of file Controller.php */
/* Location: ./system/core/Controller.php */
```

its possible becuase htaccess?

**Hint: i am searching in site, google and ... but i don't get any solution, i waste my time 2 day. :-(**

Comment: This is an old, development version of the *system/core/CodeIgniter.php* file ... When you use a dev version of anything, you do so at your own risk. You should update to the final 3.0 version.

Comment: oh thank you very much, i am do that soon. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally Its SOLVED!

just need change:

on CodeIgniter.php line 75

```
set_error_handler('_exception_handler');
```

to

```
set_exception_handler('_exception_handler');
```

Comment: This helped. Making CI no longer the error handler gave me a better stacktrace.

Comment: Finally i got a working example because of this solution.
Searched for hours and finally came across this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Took me days to find this answer!