# CodeIgniter &get_instance() not working in php5.6 version?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My codeigniter site is running properly in php5.4 version but when i upgrade my php version to php5.6.30 it is not working.

```
function &get_instance()
{       
    return CI_Controller::get_instance();
}
```

Above function is on 233 line of my file and it is returning null values.

**Error - Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in Coginiter_site\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 233**

I have trace the error point -
The code under **system/core/common.php**

```
if ( ! function_exists('load_class'))
{
    function &load_class($class, $directory = 'libraries', $prefix = 'CI_')
    {
        static $_classes = array();

        // Does the class exist?  If so, we're done...
        if (isset($_classes[$class]))
        {
            return $_classes[$class];
        }

        $name = FALSE;

        // Look for the class first in the local application/libraries folder
        // then in the native system/libraries folder
        foreach (array(APPPATH, BASEPATH) as $path)
        {
            if (file_exists($path.$directory.'/'.$class.'.php'))
            {
                $name = $prefix.$class;

                if (class_exists($name) === FALSE)
                {
                    require($path.$directory.'/'.$class.'.php');
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        // Is the request a class extension?  If so we load it too
        if (file_exists(APPPATH.$directory.'/'.config_item('subclass_prefix').$class.'.php'))
        {
            $name = config_item('subclass_prefix').$class;

            if (class_exists($name) === FALSE)
            {
                require(APPPATH.$directory.'/'.config_item('subclass_prefix').$class.'.php');
            }
        }

        // Did we find the class?
        if ($name === FALSE)
        {
            // Note: We use exit() rather then show_error() in order to avoid a
            // self-referencing loop with the Excptions class
            exit('Unable to locate the specified class: '.$class.'.php');
        }

        // Keep track of what we just loaded
        is_loaded($class);

        $_classes[$class] = new $name();
        return $_classes[$class];
    }
}
```

return empty result
This line createing a problem **$_classes[$class] = new $name();**
Please check it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter: Class 'CI\_Controller' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758681/codeigniter-class-ci-controller-not-found)

Comment: i think your system files problem i have this function on line 361. so first you backup your folder and download new codeigniter and replace system folder maybe fix your issue

Comment: can you please put your code which use &get_instance() function

Comment: $this->CI =& get_instance(); in helper and in core folder

Comment: you replace new system folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932372/codeigniter-fatal-error-class-ci-controller-not-found-after-upgrade-php-and), change on *CodeIgniter.php line 75*

```
set_error_handler('_exception_handler');
```

to

```
set_exception_handler('_exception_handler');
```

**Update:**

If this is not working, maybe you can check this others things:

1. Check if is a DB error (it's weird, but sometimes the DB error
   is shown as 'CI_Controller not found', for instance, with a bad db
   name).
2. Check if changing: `$config['log_threshold'] = 0;` works
   for you
3. Reinstall the whole CI framework system folder.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207937/codeigniter-command-line-error-php-fatal-error-class-ci-controller-not-foun) and [here](https://eftakhairul.com/weird-error-fatal-error-class-ci_controller-not-found-in-codeigniter-framework/) have the same problem, you can check all the answers.

If none of these works, try to post some code and context to your controller.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes i did this its clear to me that(& get_instance();) is given to null... under core folder file name is  MY_Controller.php

Answer (score 2):

Can you please follow the first [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758681/codeigniter-class-ci-controller-not-found) of this? Hope it will clear your problem.

Comment: My problem is not related to loading view ......... yes its related to  "Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in path\to\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 231" ..... i also did this solutions....... but i think $ci =& get_instance(); is still null here.