# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError:

Tags: php, codeigniter

I installed a software on my virtual machine and it gives this error after the login phase of the software. When I return to the home page, the problem appears to be resolved and I am logged in to the account, but I experience this problem every time I log in.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function _exception_handler(), 1 passed and exactly 4 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\public\system\core\Common.php:470 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: _exception_handler(Object(Error)) 
#1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\public\system\core\Common.php on line 470
```

Before this I was getting codeIgniter.php error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in /home/candemir.islamboltv.com/public_html/minical/public/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:233 Stack trace: 
#0 /home/candemir.islamboltv.com/public_html/minical/public/application/errors/error_404.php(58): get_instance() 
#1 /home/candemir.islamboltv.com/public_html/minical/public/system/core/Exceptions.php(146): include ('/home/candemir....') 
#2 /home/candemir.islamboltv.com/public_html/minical/public/system/core/Exceptions.php(115): CI_Exceptions->show_error() 
#3 /home /candemir.islamboltv.com/public_html/minical/public/system/core/Common.php(332): CI_Exceptions->show_404() 
#4 /home/candemir.islamboltv.com/public_html/minical/public/application/third_party /MX/Router.php(60): show_404() 
#5 /home/candemir.islamboltv.com/public_html/minical/public/system/core/Router.php(227): MX_Router->_validate_request() 
#6 / home/candemir.islamboltv.com/public_html/minical/public/system/core/Router.php(395): CI_Router->_set_request() 
#7 /home/candemir.islamboltv.com/public_html/minic in /home/candemir .islamboltv.com/public_html/minical/public/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 233
```

I solved this problem as follows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41099041 and this time I started getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function _exception_handler(), 1 passed and exactly 4 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\public\system\core\Common.php:470 Stack trace: 
#0 [internal function]: _exception_handler(Object(Error)) 
#1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\public\system\core\Common.php on line 470
```

When I tried to fix this faulty code, I started to get the errors in the screenshot, and since I thought it was a bigger error, I fixed it again:
[image: A PHP Error was encountered]

Comment: It looks like you're using an older version of CodeIgniter and a newer version of PHP. The two may not be compatible.

Comment: @aynber how do I detect it and how can I compatible it? I don't know much about this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter, so I can't tell you how to find the version. For PHP, you can do `php -v` on the command line, or create a file with `<?php phpinfo();` and view that in your web browser